# How to update and insert a document using MongoItemWriter in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

In a Spring Batch project involving reading and writing to MongoDB, writing to MongoDB using `MongoItemWriter` is configured like this:

```
<batch:job id=“someJob”>
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader=“reader”
                writer=“writer”
                processor=“processor” commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The writer bean is configured like this:

```
<bean id="writer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter">
    <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="collection"
        value="XYZCollection" />
</bean>
```

Then we have the model:

```
public class Sample {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field(“Field1”)
    private String field1;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Sample() { }

    // getter and setters

}
```

Finally, from the `processor`, the object of the class whose model makes up the MongoDB document is returned, so that the `ItemWriter` will pick it up for inserting into the database:

```
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Sample, Sample> {

    @Override
    public Sample process(Sample sampleItem) throws Exception {
        Sample updatedSampleItem = updateSampleItem(sampleItem);
        Sample newSampleItem = createSampleItem(sampleItem);
        return newSampleItem;
    }
}
```

Versions used:
- spring-core 5.1.3.RELEASE
- spring-batch 4.1.0.RELEASE
- spring-data-mongodb 2.1.3.RELEASE

Now, this saves the `newSampleItem` into `XYZCollection` as it has to. The requirement is to make Spring-Batch update the `sampleItem` that got read and then create a new document for the `newSampleItem` object. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean you wanted to update the document if it is already present ?

Comment: Yeah, if there's a document, that was read from the `ItemReader`, I want to update it and I want to create a new document corresponding to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CompositeItemWriter` with two writers, one that updates the item and another one that inserts the new document:

- For inserts, you can use the writer you already have.
- For updates, you need to create a new writer that extends `MongoItemWriter` and override `doWrite` to update the item. This is because the `MongoItemWriter` allows to either remove or save a document, but not update a document.

Then use both writers as delegates to the `CompositeItemWriter`.

Comment: In your example the `updatedSampleItem` is of type `Sample` (`Sample updatedSampleItem = updateSampleItem(sampleItem);` ), so the processor should return `Sample`.

Comment: As you mentioned, I configured the writer of the step to be a `CompositeItemWriter` containing: 1. An extension of `MongoItemWriter` with `Update` operation and 2. The `MongoItemWriter`. Then, I modified the `processor` so that it now returns the `newSampleItem` to the `CompositeItemWriter` and be availble to both the writers in it. Then, in the custom writer, I contruct the `updatedSampleItem` from `newSampleItem` and use it to update the document, and the `MongoItemWriter` writes the `newSampleItem` to the collection. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for you perfect solution.

Comment: @noob can u please share snippet of our code